# Bochs can't load img file and load it

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, bochs

Currently, I am trying to write a tiny OS from scratch. Unfortunately, In the first step, I faced a problem which drives me crazy. I write the following code as my bootloader.

```
.code16                   #generate 16-bit code
.text                     #executable code location
     .globl _start;
_start:                   #code entry point
     . = _start + 510     #mov to 510th byte from 0 pos
     .byte 0x55           #append boot signature
     .byte 0xaa           #append boot signature
```

In next step, I compile it with following commands:

```
as bootloader.s -o bootloader.o
ld –Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary bootloader.o –o bootloader.bin
```

Then I create an img file with the following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=boot.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=bootloader.bin of=boot.img
```

Finally, when I run bochs command in the terminal, Bochs just show me a dark window and nothing appeared. What is wrong?

Also, I tried the following code as bootloader but the result is same as previous.

```
.code16                  #generate 16-bit code
.text                    #executable code location
     .globl _start;

_start:                  #code entry point

     #print letter 'H' onto the screen
     movb $'H' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'e' onto the screen
     movb $'e' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'l' onto the screen
     movb $'l' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'l' onto the screen
     movb $'l' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'o' onto the screen
     movb $'o' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter ',' onto the screen
     movb $',' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print space onto the screen
     movb $' ' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'W' onto the screen
     movb $'W' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'o' onto the screen
     movb $'o' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'r' onto the screen
     movb $'r' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'l' onto the screen
     movb $'l' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     #print letter 'd' onto the screen
     movb $'d' , %al
     movb $0x0e, %ah
     int  $0x10

     . = _start + 510      #mov to 510th byte from 0 pos
     .byte 0x55            #append boot signature
     .byte 0xaa            #append boot signature
```

Comment: You should at least do something like `jmp .` at the end of the code to get into an infinite loop otherwise you'll be executing whatever happens to be in memory after that last `int  $0x10`

Comment: Preferably I'd do `endloop: hlt` `jmp endloop` instead of my simpler solution of `jmp .` in the first comment. Either one can be placed at the end of your code.

Comment: hmmm nothing appeared again. bochs just show a dark screen. :(

Comment: I've tried your code with my fix here on Bochs and it works as expected. The second example prints `Hello World` when I place `jmp .` right after the last `int $0x10` and before the boot signature.. Where did you place the `jmp .`? The first example you gave even with `jmp .` won't do a thing since it did print anything noticeable on the screen. The only other possibility is your Bochs config is messed up.

Comment: And by dark window, if you mean absolutely nothing printed in it then is there a debug window present at a prompt similar to `<bochs:1>` ? If so you may have to use the command `c` in the debugger to actually start executing the code. `c` is short for `continue`

Comment: Now bochs give me the error : Could not read the boot disk

Comment: I add it and then I compile it again. But bochs give me the error.

Comment: Add to your question your bochs configuration file.

Comment: I used ubuntu. Can you tell me how you create img file? I think this file has problem. I used dd command but the file has 512 mb. In the tutorial it must have 1 mb file.

Comment: How can I find out bochs config file?

Comment: You can build the disk image with `dd if=/dev/zero of=boot.img bs=512 count=2880`  followed by `dd if=bootloader.bin of=boot.img conv=notrunc`         . `conv=notrunc` prevents the disk image file from being truncated.

Comment: If you don't have a bochs config fie then let us see the command line you use to run Bochs.

Comment: as bootloader.s -o bootloader.o 

ld -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary bootloader.o -o bootloader.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=boot.img bs=512 count=2880
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes (1.5 MB, 1.4 MiB) copied, 0.0108683 s, 136 MB/s

dd if=bootloader.bin of=boot.img conv=notrunc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000184225 s, 2.8 MB/s

bochs

Comment: I run simply bochs and then 6 number to begin simulation. But nothing appeared.

Comment: Do you have a file in your directory called bochsrc.txt?

Comment: No i dont have this file.

Comment: Okay well that is your problem. You need to supply command line parameters or create a bochsrc.txt file that has a floppy disk that points at boot.img. The reason you have no bootable disk is because you haven't told Bochs where to boot from or what disk image file (`boot.img`) to use.

Comment: Hmmm is that possible I use something else rather floppy?

Comment: You can give a bochsrc.txt code sample?

Comment: I'll give you an example command line for bochs that doesn't require a bochsrc.txt. Try this: `bochs -q 'boot:a' 'floppya: 1_44=boot.img, status=inserted'`   . That should tell Bochs that you will be booting from Drive A and that it is a 1.44MB floppy and the contents will be in the fie `boot.img` and will start out as _inserted_.

Comment: haa thanksss broo. now everything works fine..

Comment: You need to create a bochsrc.txt file.  For more info look here : http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.txt.  If you are in Windows you can directly download my bootloader and see the bochsrc.txt. Your self : https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror_Win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a bochs file in order it works well. Also You can use virtual machine. I test your code and it works fine.